# rollback pipewire to PulseAudio

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

My bluetooth headphones are lagging video and stuttering.

I have recently switched to pipewire and find the documentation too advanced to navigate.There are so many layers of configuration and the service has not been adopted for long enough to grow a good body of support.

So I want to rollback to Pulse which has more developed documentation and support.

I'm on Arch and find when I try to remove pipewire I find it has many dependents whose integration I don't understand well enough to confidently address.

```
 # pacman -R pipewire
 checking dependencies...
 error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
 :: removing pipewire breaks dependency 'pipewire' required by helvum
 :: removing pipewire breaks dependency 'pipewire' required by obs-studio
 :: removing pipewire breaks dependency 'pipewire' required by pipewire-media-session
 :: removing pipewire breaks dependency 'libpipewire-0.3.so=0-64' required by pipewire-media-session
 :: removing pipewire breaks dependency 'libpipewire-0.3.so=0-64' required by pipewire-pulse
```

How can I remove or disable pipewire and return to pulse?

Or maybe someone has a suggestion for approaching the bluetooth problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `-R` flag. Rather use `sudo pacman -S pulseaudio pulseaudio-bluetooth`. Pacman will prompt PipeWire Pulse and PulseAudio are in conflict, and if you want to remove PipeWire. Press Y and you're done.

If you insist to use `-R` then use `-Rsdd` to skip depndency check and then install PulseAudio though the use of the flag is extremely unrecommended. You should've used the `s` flag anyway, else `pipewire-media-session` and `pipewire-pulse` would left behind. The best way to do such removal is to remove the explicitly installed package with `-Rs` flag and the dependencies will be automatically taken care of.

Comment: Thanks wish I'd known. Before reading your post I simply ran `pacman -R` on each of the dependencies and then re-installed all the pulse packages.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing `sudo pacman -S pulseaudio pulseaudio-bluetooth` did replace some pipewire stuff, but didn't fully switch to pulse, as the pipewire server still did start at boot and was blocking all audio. The only way to fix my audio was to do `pkill pipewire`

What helped me was doing:

```
systemctl --user disable pipewire pipewire.socket
systemctl --user mask pipewire pipewire.socket
```

Now I don't need to do multiple "pkill pipewire" after booting OS to have my audio working. (and yes, pipewire behave very bad on my very old Antergos installation including random 10s audio playback delays, so I'm forced to use pulseaudio that do work flawless from the start on my 5year installation)